# How many 18650 cells in series for 48V Li-Ion pack

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, batteries

I'm looking at the [Samsung 35e](https://www.orbtronic.com/content/samsung-35e-datasheet-inr18650-35e.pdf) and trying to build a 48V pack.

I'm trying to figure out how many I should put in series to get 48V. I'm assuming I use the nominal voltage to spec that (3.6V/cell)? Should I do 13 in series (3.6V/cell * 13 cell = 46.8V) or 14 (3.6V/cell * 14 cells = 50.4V)?

Comment: Your application will dictate what you should do.  We can only guess. I would tend towards 50.4V knowing that battery voltage goes down over time. But the fully charged state might be too high for your components....it's up to you.

Comment: One consideration : the rest of the system must be designed to survive the fully charged state : usually taken as 4.2V/cell, perhaps err on the cautious side and rate it for 4.3V/cell.

Comment: Keep in mind that for electrochemical cells, and hence battery packs, the voltage rating is nominal.  A lead-acid cell is nominally 2.0V, but fully charged it's 2.2V, and "fully discharged" depends on the cell construction and how willing you are to damage it, but is probably around 1.6V to 1.8V.  So a "48V" lead-acid battery will have a voltage range of 52.8V down to 43V or even 38V, depending on the original design intent.

Comment: So -- it appears that your real question is "what are the voltage limits for my actual device, and how can I determine that".  If you tell us what it is, and what is currently feeding it 48V, that would help.  Or if it has an input power specification, that should say what the input voltage range is.

Comment: @TimWescott Thanks for the help. It's hard to tell what the limits are for my devices since it's not published in any of their respective datasheets. I'm leaning towards 14S at this point as it seems it'll give me more usable range? The nominal voltage at 13S is already below 48V. That being said if I charge at 4.2V/cell that would leave me at 58.8V and I'm not sure if my devices would rather be under or overvolted.

Comment: @fullyjosh how do you know it needs 48 volts? If you link to the product data sheet you might get better help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your devices would rather not be overvolted.

Comment: 48V lithium-ion batteries usually use a 13S configuration (e.g. E-Bike). But as the others have stated out, check the requirements of your application.